# Implementing the Facebook Login v2.3 and fetching user data

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to implement the facebook login. I have followed everything from here.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.3

And I am trying to make a Graph API call to retrieve user data; however, when I do so I get this.

```
Warning: Request without access token missing application ID or client token.
```

I believe I have implemented this login correctly and followed all the steps.

I have done some research on this and since sessions are deprecated in this current Facebook API version it has been of no help.

Is there anything blatantly wrong with my implementation that would cause Facebook Login not to be validated for the user?

```
package com.ro.hitup1_0;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.Signature;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.AccessTokenTracker;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.GraphRequest;
import com.facebook.GraphResponse;
import com.facebook.Profile;
import com.facebook.ProfileTracker;
import com.facebook.login.LoginManager;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    //Give your SharedPreferences file a name and save it to a static variable
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
    //Facebook button
    LoginButton loginButton;
    Button email_button;
    Button google_button;
    CallbackManager callbackManager;
    AccessTokenTracker accessTokenTracker;
    ProfileTracker profileTracker;
    JSONArray userInformation;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();





        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);


        loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email", "user_friends"));
        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
                new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        // App code
                        Log.e("loginResult: ", loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken());
                        //LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(LoginActivity.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email", "user_friends"));

                        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                                loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onCompleted(
                                            JSONObject object,
                                            GraphResponse response) {
                                        // Application code
                                        response.getError();
                                        Log.e("JSON: ", object.toString());




                                    }
                                });
                        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                        parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,link");
                        request.setParameters(parameters);
                        //Log.e(" About to Graph Call", " ");
                        request.executeAsync();
                        //Log.e(" Finished Graph Call", " ");


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        // App code
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                        // App code
                        Log.e("Facebook exception: ", exception.getMessage());
                    }
                });




        // Callback registration
        //make sure to redirect to main page
        accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(
                    AccessToken oldAccessToken,
                    AccessToken currentAccessToken) {

                // App code
            }
        };

        profileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(
                    Profile oldProfile,
                    Profile currentProfile) {
                // App code
            }

        };


        google_button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.google_button);
        google_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });

        email_button= (Button)findViewById(R.id.email_button);
        email_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });


        try {
            PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                    "com.ro.hitup1_0",
                    PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_login, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        profileTracker.stopTracking();
    }





}
```

I implemented this in a FragmentActivity is there anything wrong with doing so?

What am I missing and why is this occuring?

For additional context (no android pun intended),

https://github.com/rrtigga/Hitup1.0/tree/master/app/src/main

Thanks.

Comment: Is your callback's onSuccess() called? And if so, is there an access token in the LoginResult?

Comment: Okay Ill put my edited code. How do I use that accesstoken across my application. (in other activities